# What is the role of the Laplace transform in the topological recursion formalism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, recurrences, laplace-transform

While reading papers on topological recursion, among them *The Laplace transform, mirror symmetry, and the topological recursion of Eynard–Orantin* by M. Mulase, they describe the mirror symmetry between models, induced by the Laplace transform, which is clear in many examples such as the Mirzakhani's recursion case. But I was wondering: What is the specific analytic property or formula of the Laplace transform that gives rise to this? I don't know if it has been identified or what's the progress on that question, which is also raised in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5224.pdf (paraphrased as looking for the inverse Laplace transform of general topological recursions) and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1159.pdf (Conjecture 1.5)